# Multivariate log-normal distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

Let $X=\mu + \Sigma^{1/2}Z$ and $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$. Is there a closed form for the distribution of $\exp(X)$?

Comment: by $\exp(X)$ do you mean the componentwise $\exp$?

Comment: Yes. I mean componentwise

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation capital sigma to the 1/2. I realize you're taking a sum, but what exactly are you summing?

Comment: Sigma is the covariance matrix

Comment: Basically,  X is normally distributed with mean mu and covariance matrix Sigma

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Multivariate_log-normal  and http://isi.cbs.nl/iamamember/CD2/pdf/329.PDF  which has a density.

Comment: It's a simple change of variable.  One expression for the *density* function appears in the question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65998.  There is no closed form for the distribution function in terms of standard elementary functions (just as in the univariate case).  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multivariate+lognormal for closely related questions.