# Multivariate log-normal probabiltiy density function (PDF)

Tags: multivariate-analysis, density-function, lognormal-distribution

The Multivariate Gaussian pdf is given by

$$(2\pi)^{-\frac{K}{2}} \det(\Sigma)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \exp({-\frac{1}{2}}(X-\mu)' \Sigma^{-1} (X-\mu)) $$

The wikipedia for multivariate Gaussians is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)

However I could not find a pdf for the multivariate lognormal distribution. Does it exist? If so, what is it?

Comment: Certainly it exists!  An expression for it appears in the question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65998 .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness, I'll provide an answer here.  This is a simple application of the multivariate change of variables theorem: say $Y = \Phi(X)$ where $\Phi$ is a smooth bijective function.  Then

$$
p_Y(y) = p_X(\Phi^{-1}(y)) \vert \det J_{\Phi^{-1}}(y)\vert 
$$ where $J_{\Phi^{-1}}$ is the Jacobian matrix of the inverse transformation.  So for a multivariate lognormal random variable $Y = \exp(Z)$ where $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$, we have $\Phi^{-1}(y) = \ln(y)$ and so

$$
J_{\Phi^{-1}}(y) = \text{diag}(1/y_1,\ldots,1/y_n)
$$ Hence

$$
\vert \det J_{\Phi^{-1}}(y)\vert = \prod_{j=1}^ny_j^{-1} = \frac{1}{y_1y_2\cdots y_n}
$$  So, finally we have

$$
p_Y(y) = (2\pi)^{-n/2}(\det\Sigma)^{-1/2}\prod_{j=1}^ny_j^{-1}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\ln(y)-\mu)^t\Sigma^{-1}(\ln(y) - \mu)\right)
$$

Comment: just in case anyone is interested, the entropy of this multivariate log-normal is $$H(Y) = \frac{n}{2}(1+ \log(2\pi)) + \log(\det(\Sigma))/2 + \sum_j \mu_j$$