# Gaussian Log Probability

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution, actor-critic

I have a code segment from this repo:

https://github.com/toshikwa/slac.pytorch/blob/master/slac/utils.py

[image]

I am reading a paper about Soft Actor-Critic, a reinforcement learning algorithm. They have you sample from a Gaussian Log distribution. I believe that would mean you use the PDF to sample from. I am making a lot of assumptions, so please correct me.

I found this post discussing taking a multivariate Gaussian pdf, making it log Gaussian.

[Multivariate log-normal probabiltiy density function (PDF)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214997/multivariate-log-normal-probabiltiy-density-function-pdf?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The problem is that equation listed doesn't seem to match the code.

[image]

Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree.If I need to be more concise or give more information please let me know. Any direction would be so awesome.

To clarify, I'm trying to figure out where the code is pulling the formula for Gaussian log prob if it doesn't match the PDF.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the equation in the code, if it the log gaussian then why does it not match.

Comment: But this isn't the multivariate distribution, but univariate.

Comment: The formula is correct.  The code seems to omit the factors of $y_j^{-1}.$